# Paging in my web page

Tags: asp.net

I have a large data set and i have to apply paging on that data set and after that the result set should be another data set. What is the reliable method to achieve that.

I have tried with 'PagedDataSource' class but i don't know how it is possible to convert to dataset or data table.

In my case i need a general solution. I have to bind to a control like gridview as well as i have to used it with normal html table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this article doing same thing you want : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/EnhanceGrid.aspx

following sp returns record that you want

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRequestedRecordByPage] 
 @FromList nvarchar(200)              -- Table Name  
,@SortingCol nvarchar(200)         -- Sorting column Name
,@SelectList nvarchar(200) = '*'         -- Select columns list
,@WhereClause nvarchar(200) = ''        -- Where clause i.e condition
,@PageNum int = 1                           -- Requested page number
,@PageSize int = 5                 -- No of record in page
,@TotalNoOfRecord int output         -- Total no of selected records
AS 
Begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
  DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)         -- query going to be execute

  IF rtrim(ltrim(@WhereClause)) <> '' 
  BEGIN
      SET @Query ='SELECT   @TotalNoOfRecord = COUNT(*) 
                      FROM     ' + @FromList + ' 
        WHERE    ' + @WhereClause 
  END
  ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      SET @Query ='SELECT   @TotalNoOfRecord = COUNT(*) 
                      FROM     ' + @FromList 
  END

    /* Count no. of record */
       EXEC sp_executeSQL 
        @Query, 
        @params = N'@TotalNoOfRecord INT OUTPUT', 
         = @TotalNoOfRecord OUTPUT 

DECLARE @lbound int, @ubound int 




/* Calculating upper and lower bound */
        SET @lbound = ((@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize) 
        SET @ubound = @lbound + @PageSize + 1 


/* Get list of record(s) */
        SELECT @Query =  ''
        SELECT @Query =  'SELECT  * 
                          FROM    ( 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @SortingCol  + ') AS rownumber,' +@SelectList  +   
                                        ' FROM    ' + @FromList 

        IF rtrim(ltrim(@WhereClause)) <> '' 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Query = @Query + ' WHERE   ' + @WhereClause 
        END

            SELECT @Query = @Query + '     ) AS tbl 
WHERE rownumber > ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @lbound) + 
      ' AND rownumber < ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @ubound) 

       EXEC (@Query)                 
End
```